# Blend error "the name xx does not exist in the namespace yy" - but works fine in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, wpf-controls, blend, expression-blend-4

So I've been working on a WPF project with Visual Studio 2010 for awhile. I'm using several class library projects with WPF controls that I wrote. Today I opened the solution in Blend for the first time, and it showed me many errors like this:

"the name xxx does not exist in the namespace yy"

Looking at the assembly, I can see that the class appears at that namespace. Also if it didn't, Visual Studio wouldn't have compiled it, right?

I checked similar questions, and no, I don't have the x86 build platform thing, all my DLL's are .Net 4.0, and no missing references.

Is there anything else?

Comment: All your SDKs correct / installed? For Blend, not VS.

Comment: this is happening to me in vs 2013 RC and blend 2013 RC. It was working before and stopped working all of a sudden. It compiles in vs but blend wont compile it.

Comment: Happening for me too (Blend for VS 2012 Update 3).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some Bug in Blend. I fixed this by removing the project references and then adding it back again